# how can i invoke an object from a different class?

Tags: java

I have four classes, the main class, a "MyFrame" class, a "MyButton" class and a MySecondFrame class. In a method in the MyButton class i want to set the visibility to the a second frame i created in the main class to true and the visibility to the first frame to false (also created in the main class). Now I have got the problem that i cant call the to frames in order set their visibility to true or false. How can I solve this? (its an cannot resolve symbol error)
Heres the code:

```
package com.company;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyFrame firstFrame = new MyFrame();
    MyButton firstButton = new MyButton();
    //MyTextField firstTextField = new MyTextField();
    MySecondFrame secondFrame = new MySecondFrame();
    MyLabel firstLabel = new MyLabel();
    firstFrame.add(firstButton);
    
    //secondFrame.add(firstTextField);
    //secondFrame.add(firstLabel);
}
}

package com.company;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class MyFrame extends JFrame{

MyFrame(){
    this.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(0xD3D3D3));
    this.setSize(500, 700);
    this.setLocation(870,15);
    this.setResizable(false);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setTitle("Converter");
    this.setLayout(null);
}
}

package com.company;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class MyButton extends JButton implements ActionListener{


MyButton(){
    this.setBounds(150, 100, 200, 50);
    this.setText("Convert Currencies");
    this.setFocusable(false);
    this.setVisible(true);
    }
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(e.getSource()==this){
        firstFrame.setVisible(false);
        secondFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
package com.company;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class MySecondFrame extends JFrame {
MySecondFrame(){
    this.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(0xD3D3D3));
    this.setSize(500, 700);
    this.setLocation(870,15);
    this.setResizable(false);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setTitle("Converter");
    this.setLayout(null);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can achive what you want passing an interface from Main class to MyButton class.

Firstly, you define an interface

```
interface ButtonListener{
     void onClick();
}
```

Secondly, change MyButton's constructor

```
public class MyButton extends JButton implements ActionListener{

private ButtonListener buttonListener;

MyButton(ButtonListener buttonListener){
    this.buttonListener = buttonListener;
    this.setBounds(150, 100, 200, 50);
    this.setText("Convert Currencies");
    this.setFocusable(false);
    this.setVisible(true);
}
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(e.getSource()==this){
         buttonListener.onClick();
    }
}
```

Finally, pass this interface to your MyButton class

```
public class Main implements ButtonListener {

    MyFrame firstFrame;
    MySecondFrame secondFrame;

    public Main(){
        firstFrame = new MyFrame();
        secondFrame = new MySecondFrame();

        MyButton firstButton = new MyButton(this);
        //MyTextField firstTextField = new MyTextField();
        MyLabel firstLabel = new MyLabel();
        firstFrame.add(firstButton);

        //secondFrame.add(firstTextField);
        //secondFrame.add(firstLabel);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main main = Main();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick() {
        //here, your button event triggered
        //do what you want
        firstFrame.setVisible(false);
        secondFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: 'com.company.Main.this' cannot be referenced from a static context

Comment: 'onClick()' in 'com.company.Main' clashes with 'onClick()' in 'com.company.ButtonListener'; attempting to assign weaker access privileges ('package-private'); was 'public'

Comment: What do the first two errors mean and why can't it still not resolve symbols firstFrame and Second frame?

Comment: I updated, put 'public' in  @Override   public void onClick() {

Comment: Also, I did not write other classes. I wrote just codes you must be add

Comment: I updated my answer again. Try the current answer